# What's Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured) doing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights, telemetry

I'm running an `MVC` app in VS 2015. During debug mode, everything is work just fine until when I try to create new user.

The create form works also the save button. But the new data is not showing in the index but the new edit/details/delete is the index.

The output tell:
Application Insights Telemetry (reconfigured):

> {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.PerformanceCounter","time":"2016-04-20T10:41:44.1380123+08:00","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"1.2.3.490","ai.device.roleInstance":"KL-PT-049.icarasia.local","ai.application.ver":"Unknown","ai.device.type":"PC","ai.device.id":"KL-PT-049.icarasia.local","ai.device.oemName":"Hewlett-Packard","ai.device.model":"HP
>   ProBook
>   4440s","ai.device.network":"Wireless80211","ai.device.language":"en-MY"},"data":{"baseType":"PerformanceCounterData","baseData":{"ver":2,"categoryName":"Processor","counterName":"%
>   Processor
>   Time","instanceName":"_Total","value":23.789436340332,"properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}

I wonder is there any relation between create user and application insight telemetry? Thanks

[Click here for picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvkVT.png)

Answer (score 17):

No, it is not related. You enabled Application Insights by installing nuget nuget packages but you did not configure it by providing an instrumentation key.

So in debug Application Insights telemetry is collected (in your case it is a performance counter) but it is not sent anywhere.

Application Insights Hub in VS 2015 listens to these events and provides nice UI for analyzing the events (`View` ->`Other Windows`->`Application Insights Search`).

If you like insights that provides you should create Azure resource and add iKey to application insights config ([Getting Started](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-get-started/)). If you do not find it useful - uninstall nuget packages.

Comment: Yea, you're right. After couple times tracing from debug mode, it turns out the problem come from my stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: do you know what happens when App insights are enable but instrumentation key is not provided? is this dangerous in anyway? will the events / telemetry be simply dropped or will there be some buffer growing? Cannot find any definitive documentation on this...

Comment: I had a similar issue I had hit the quota..
"Data collection stopped due to daily limit of free data reached"